# Can you help me find out what this guy's name is?

Tags: cipher

I'm a publisher. Yesterday I received an email from someone who wanted me to publish his book. However, he refused to send it to me unless I figured out his name. I sent back an email with the answer 'Rumplestiltskin', but he said no. Instead, he sent me this:

> **bar.gjb.gjb.gjb.gjb/gjb.gjb.gjb.gjb.bar|bar.bar.bar.bar.bar|bar.bar.bar.bar.bar ^ 
>
>   bar.gjb.gjb.gjb.gjb|bar.bar.gjb.gjb.gjb/bar.bar.bar.bar.bar ^ 
> bar.bar.bar.bar.bar|bar.gjb.gjb.gjb.gjb/bar.bar.gjb.gjb.gjb ^
>
>   bar.bar.bar.bar.bar|bar.gjb.gjb.gjb.gjb/bar.bar.gjb.gjb.gjb <> 
>
>   bar.bar.bar.bar.bar|bar.gjb.gjb.gjb.gjb/bar.bar.bar.gjb.gjb ^ 
>
>   bar.bar.bar.bar.bar|bar.bar.bar.bar.bar <> 
>
>   bar.gjb.gjb.gjb.gjb|gjb.gjb.gjb.gjb.bar|bar.bar.gjb.gjb.gjb/bar.bar.bar.bar.bar ^ 
>
>   bar.bar.bar.bar.bar|bar.gjb.gjb.gjb.gjb/gjb.gjb.gjb.gjb.bar ^ 
>
>   bar.gjb.gjb.gjb.gjb|bar.bar.gjb.gjb.gjb/bar.bar.bar.bar.bar|bar.bar.bar.gjb.gjb|gjb.gjb.gjb.bar.bar ^ 
>
>   bar.bar.bar.bar.bar|bar.gjb.gjb.gjb.gjb/bar.bar.bar.gjb.gjb ^ 
>
>   bar.gjb.gjb.gjb.gjb|bar.bar.gjb.gjb.gjb/bar.bar.bar.bar.bar ^ 
>
>   bar.bar.bar.bar.bar|bar.bar.bar.bar.bar ^ 
>
>   bar.bar.bar.bar.bar|bar.gjb.gjb.gjb.gjb/bar.bar.gjb.gjb.gjb**

Can you help me figure out what Mr. Bar Gjb's real name is?

Hint 1:

> 13. Decaying.

Hint 2:

> What's an anagram of *here come dots*?

Comment: Is there supposed to be one more '^' or '<>' after the last line?

Comment: Yet another cipher with no context.

Comment: Perhaps the word gibberish in the title means something?

Comment: Maybe Hint 2 is an anagram for "the morse code"?

Comment: Shouldn't the fifth and tenth lines be the same? Or maybe I just _want_ them to be the same, so that my answer fits better. `:)`

Comment: @MOehm I salute you. You probably have the right answer.

Comment: Your comment makes me confident that I have, but I'm still missing a step. I'll post a partial answer, maybe someone else can fill it in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first hint...

> ... alludes to rot13 encoding, which converts **bar** and **gjb** to **one** and **two**. <sub>Confirmed by OP</sub>

The second hint...

> ... refers to Morse code. <sub>Confirmed by OP</sub>

The bar/gjb sequences are...

> ... organised in groups of five. In Morse code, the numerals all have five signals. Taking bar/one as dit and gjb/two as dah, the message reads:
>
>  1 / 9 | 5 | 5 ^
>  1 | 2 / 5 ^
>  5 | 1 / 2 ^
>  5 | 1 / 2 <>
>  5 | 1 / 3 ^
>  5 | 5 <>
>  1 | 9 | 2 / 5 ^
>  5 | 1 / 9 ^
>  1 | 2 / 5 | 3 | 8 ^
>  5 | 1 / 3 ^
>  1 | 2 / 5 ^
>  5 | 5 ^
>  5 | 1 / 2
>
> <sub>Confirmed by OP</sub>

Each line...

> ... represents a letter. The caret denotes the end of a letter, the diamond denotes the end of a word.  <sub>Confirmed by OP</sub>
>
>  As [@yuzuki](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25542/yuzuki) observed in a comment, the slash probably means that two adjacent digits are joined into a larger number. After joining the numbers and removing the end markers of the letters, we get:
>
>  19 | 5 | 5
>  1 | 25
>  5 | 12
>  5 | 12
>  5 | 13
>  5 | 5
>  1 | 9 | 25
>  5 | 19
>  1 | 25 | 3 | 8
>  5 | 13
>  1 | 25
>  5 | 5
>  5 | 12

The next step is...

> ... to convert the numbers to letters. The number represents the position of the letter in the alphabet, so 1 is A, 2 is B and so on:
>
>  see ay el el / em ee / aiy es aych em ay ee el
>
>  These are the letters as they are spelt when read out loud. (Although I'd have used ELL and AITCH.)

The sentence reads:

> `CALL ME ISHMAEL`
>
>   which is the famous opening line from Herman Melville's *Moby-Dick*. So the author's name is Ishmael. (The name could also be Herman Melville, but nobody will know the famous quote if the book hasn't been published.)

Footnote:

> I had found the answer without figuring out the second step, where series of numbers are treated as letters. It was enough to treat each individual sequence of numbers, say `5|12`, as a letter in a monoalphabetic substitution cipher. Just finding that the caret and diamond are letter and word separators was enough to attack the monoalphabetic cipher.

Comment: Ah, thanks, both for the confirmations and corrections. 1/3 fits better with the rest of the patterns, where the smaller number is always left of the slash.

Comment: Observation: 5 | 1 / 9 --> 5 | 19 --> S (19th letter of the alphabet). Holds true for all number sequences that start with 5.

Comment: You have 5|1|2 instead of 5|1/2

Comment: @Mithrandir I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Just saw it XD quite a minor edit though, was surprised it warranted a comment.

Comment: @yuzuki: That was a brilliant observation! That means that the slash juxtaposes digits. The pattern 5 + letter code works because the 5 is in reality an e and the codes read EL, EM, ES and EE. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @MOehm Heh I think your subsequent observation was more incredible XD Congrats on solving the puzzle!